# How do i compress any image and Excel and CSV files in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

i need to compress all types of files using React js
Please help
Currently there is Compressor.js for image compression but i need CSV Excel files also to be compressed

Answer (score 0):

You can use zlib to compress files.

To install zlib use: `npm install zlib`

Refer the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zlib).

Comment: by this its possible to convert to zip file but the file size is not reduced

Comment: I didn't try that library. I will try and find a good library if this is not an optimal one.

Comment: Please share that

Answer (score 0):

You can use fflate, it has the best compression time and lowest minified bundle size.

check out the docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fflate.

Npm install command: `npm i fflate`